# Remove empty space between content in column and the edge of column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, spaces

```
        <div class="row mt-5 d-flex">
            <div class="col-md-3 p-5 mt-3">
                <img id="image" class="align-self-center" 
                src="background1.jpg" 
                width="80%" height="100%"/>
            </div>   

            <div class="col-md-4 align-self-center">
                <span id="text">
                    text
                </span>
             </div> 

            <div class="col-md-5 background-image">

            </div>
       </div>
```

Result:
[image: Result]
I don't know why the empty space between the rounded image and the end of column is there. I use bootstrap. I've put borders around divs with "col-md-*" in order to see the edges correctly.

I tried setting padding and margin to 0 but there weren't any changes. I think it has to do something with the "img" tag (I also tried setting it to be displayed as a block).

Answer (score -1):

Check for any padding or margin. usually bootstrap adds those properties automatically with col-md-** classes. You might have to override those classes. I would use the inspect element tool to track them.